# My VPN seems to have broken my internet

Tags: vpn

I installed Windscribe VPN and it's Chrome Extension last night. Everything connected and worked appropriately. I left it on overnight along with a Torrent program set to turn my computer off after the download was complete.

Upon bootup this morning, nothing on my PC will connect to the internet except for IE. All internet related options on all other devices in the house work, so I know the problem is isolated to my PC.

I have reset all of my internet options and attempted a plethora of less clearly related solutions. Any ideas would be great.

- I have uninstalled and reinstalled  Chrome (where I thought the problem first was sourced)
- I have cleared my DNS through some form of command prompt command
- I have cleared Chrome's Cache through some form of Chrome command (I cannot remember these commands )
- I have reset my Ipv4 settings on all of my connections
- I have forgotten and relearned my wifi connection
- I have reset my router
- I have reinstalled the VPN to attempt to play with it's settings
- I have manually changed my Ipv4 DNS settings to specific configurations following a thread that claimed it fixed kill-switch errors...
- I have turned OFF windows Firewall to see if that was causing the problem and still could not connect properly to websites and such with anything but IE
- More as I remember\Try them

Note Chrome cant even access my router on my network, something is clearly wrong with my settings somewhere.

Edit: This was asked for, The [Route Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTZlU.jpg)

Comment: Please list the "plethora of less clearly related solutions" so that we know what not to recommend.

Comment: what do you mean by elevated command? im about to punch that into command prompt just in case but if that's not what you meant then im lost

Comment: Elevated as in "as admin".